# Сортировка списка с числами

Tags: excel, vba

Есть макро, с помощью которого получаю список файлов из папки с атрибутами:

```
Имя файла, Размер, Дата изменения
```

[image: список файлов]

Но полученный список сортируется неправильно.

Как отсортировать список с макро, либо же другим способом корректно?
Чтобы порядок был таким:

> Том 1
>   Том 2
>   Том 3
>   Том ..
>   Том 12

Пробовал настраиваемой сортировкой, не выходит.

Код макроса, смотрящего в папку с файлами:

```
Sub FileList()
    Dim V As String
    Dim BrowseFolder As String 
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Выберите папку или диск"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        V = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Вы ничего не выбрали!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    BrowseFolder = CStr(V)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheet.Name = "Список файлов"
    With Range("M1:Q1")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With
    Range("O1").Value = "Имя файла"
    Range("P1").Value = "Размер"
    Range("Q1").Value = "Дата изменения"

    ListFilesInFolder BrowseFolder, True End Sub Private Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal SourceFolderName As String, ByVal IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SourceFolder As Object
    Dim SubFolder As Object
    Dim FileItem As Object
    Dim r As Long
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.getfolder(SourceFolderName)
    r = Range("A2").Row + 1
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(r, 15).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Dim siz As Long
        siz = FileItem.Size
        Cells(r, 16).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 _ байт"
        Cells(r, 16).Value = siz
        Cells(r, 17).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        r = r + 1
        X = SourceFolder.Path
    Next FileItem
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If
    Columns("O:Q").AutoFit
    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Добавьте примеры кода которые сделали вы. Иначе это получается, что вы хотите, чтобы сделали все за вас.

Comment: эм...код? Несортированный список из exel вам показать? 
Я спросил как, но не прошу это делать. Мне пары идей было бы достаточно.

Comment: Самым простым выходом полагаю введение дополнительного (возможно, скрытого) столбца (а при сортировке в макросе - соотв. функция сравнения), в котором все числа (или по крайней мере номера тома) дополнены до фиксированной длины ведущими нулями и однообразно отформатированы (скажем, удалены скобки и заменены на точки). Именно по нему и выполняется сортировка. Кстати, тогда и слово "Том" можно выбросить...

Comment: Самый правильный способ:  еще при  получении данных название (номер) тома выводить в отдельный столбец (В имени файла или оставлять, или удалять). При этом значение менять на числовое, иначе с текстовым вариантом получится неправильная сортировка. И разобраться с номерами: 4.2 и 12(2) - разный формат. Покажете код - допилим.

Comment: Добавил код макроса.

Answer (score 0):

Если без доработки старого макроса или написания нового - формула. Убираем первое слово, меняем точку и открывающую скобку на запятую, закрывающую скобку удаляем, преобразовываем в число:

```
=--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ЛЕВБ(ПСТР(M2;5;9);ПОИСК(" ";ПСТР(M2;5;9))-1);".";",");"(";",");")";)
```